# Incomming local SIP calls. What's the cause?

Tags: linux, networking, voip, sip

I have Linphone installed on Linux. There is default identity set to `me@192.168.1.100`.

I keep getting incomming calls from numbers like `100@192.168.1.100` or `7070@192.168.1.100`. What is the cause of those calls?

Changing local port from 5060 to something else would do the trick but I wonder what is causing those calls. I haven't forwarded that port to `192.168.1.100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is automated bots scanning the Internet for open SIP hosts – check with a packet capture tool such as tcpdump, tshark, Wireshark.

For example, here's what `tcpdump` shows (our whole subnet received those just moments ago):

```
16:05:29.914631 IP 50.62.22.192.5172 > 192.0.2.246.5060: SIP, length: 407
E.....@.4...2>.......4......OPTIONS sip:100@192.0.2.246 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5172;branch=Z9Hg4Bk-409333146;rport
Content-Length: 0
From: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=6330303030326636313363340132373131383732373731
Accept: application/sdp
User-Agent: friendly-scanner
To: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>
Contact: sip:100@127.0.0.1:5172
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Call-ID: 984345958051304257309960
Max-Forwards: 70
```

Note that many SIP clients try to set up port-forwarding automatically, e.g. using UPnP.

Assuming it's *actually* sipvicious, see also https://serverfault.com/questions/549134.